# Script throws an error while using a particular link among several

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a script using `scrapy` in combination with `selenium` to parse the name of `CEO`'s of different companies from a webpage. You can find the name of different companies in the landing page. However, you can get the name of `CEO`'s once you click on the name of the company links.

The following script can parse the links of different companies and use those links to scrape the names of `CEO`'S except for the second company. ***When the script tries to parse the name of `CEO` using the link of the second company, it encounters `stale element reference error`. The script fetches the rest of the results in the right way even when It encountered that error along the way.*** Once again - it only throws error parsing the information using the second company link. How weird!!

[The webpage link](http://fortune.com/fortune500/list/)

This is what I've tried so far with:

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class FortuneSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'fortune'
    url = 'http://fortune.com/fortune500/list/'

    def start_requests(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver,10)
        yield scrapy.Request(self.url,callback=self.get_links)

    def get_links(self,response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        for item in self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class*="searchResults__title--"]'))):
            company_link = item.find_element_by_css_selector('a[class*="searchResults__cellWrapper--"]').get_attribute("href")
            yield scrapy.Request(company_link,callback=self.get_inner_content)

    def get_inner_content(self,response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        chief_executive = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//tr[td[.="CEO"]]//td[contains(@class,"dataTable__value--")]/div'))).text
        yield {'CEO': chief_executive}
```

This is the type of results I'm getting:

```
Jeffrey P. Bezos

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

Darren W. Woods
Timothy D. Cook
Warren E. Buffett
Brian S. Tyler
C. Douglas McMillon
David S. Wichmann
Randall L. Stephenson
Steven H. Collis
and so on------------
```

> ***How can I fix the error that my script encounters while dealing with the second company link?***

PS I can use their api to get all the information but I'm curious to know why this weird trouble the above script is facing.

Comment: @AndiCover the question you linked got a `StaleReferenceError` due to a copy/paste typo, and should probably be closed.  If you see a typo in OP's code, it would be nice of you to point it out, then flag the question as off topic (but not as a duplicate).  Marking this as a duplicate does nothing but waste everyone's time.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly modified approach should get you all the desired content from that site without any issues. All you need to do is store all the target links as a list within `get_links()` method and use `return` or `yield` while making callback to `get_inner_content()` method. You can also disable the images to make the script slightly faster.

The following attempt should get you all the results:

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class FortuneSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'fortune'
    url = 'http://fortune.com/fortune500/list/'

    def start_requests(self):
        option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_prefs = {}
        option.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
        chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
        chrome_prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver,10)
        yield scrapy.Request(self.url,callback=self.get_links)

    def get_links(self,response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        item_links = [item.get_attribute("href") for item in self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class*="searchResults__title--"] a[class*="searchResults__cellWrapper--"]')))]
        return [scrapy.Request(link,callback=self.get_inner_content) for link in item_links]

    def get_inner_content(self,response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        chief_executive = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//tr[td[.="CEO"]]//td[contains(@class,"dataTable__value--")]/div'))).text
        yield {'CEO': chief_executive}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(FortuneSpider)
    process.start()
```

Or using `yield`:

```
def get_links(self,response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    item_links = [item.get_attribute("href") for item in self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class*="searchResults__title--"] a[class*="searchResults__cellWrapper--"]')))]
    for link in item_links:
        yield scrapy.Request(link,callback=self.get_inner_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `Stale Element Exception` because on line 24 you are navigating away from the original page.

```py
    def get_inner_content(self,response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        ...
```

Since you are looping through the links on line 19...

```
 for item in self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class*="searchResults__title--"]'))):
```

Any subsequent access to `item` will be rendered as a `Stale Element Exception` if you try to perform an access on it since the page was navigated away from in the context of `driver`.

Your script will work for "Walmart" since it's the first `item`.  You are getting this error on `Exxon Mobil` because the page was then navigated away from on line 24.

Comment: I would be satisfied if i could see that as soon as the script throws the above error, it does not work for the rest of the links but the thing is it throws that error only for the second link. The rest are getting parsed in the right way. Refer to the result above.

Answer (score 0):

To parse the name of CEO's of different companies from the webpage `https://fortune.com/fortune500/search/` [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) alone itself would be enough and you  need to:

- [Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681172/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-scroll-options/54689339#54689339) to the last item on the webpage.
- [Collect the *href* attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56439472/how-to-extract-all-the-texts-from-a-tag-using-selenium-through-python/56439784#56439784) and store in a list.
- Open the *hrefs* in the [adjascent *tab*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640584/how-to-open-each-product-within-a-website-in-a-new-tab-for-scrapping-using-selen/57641549#57641549)
- Switch the focus to the newly opened [*tab*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python/51893230#51893230) and induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Code Block:

    ```
    # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://fortune.com/fortune500/search/")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Explore Lists from Other Years']"))))
    my_hrefs = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@class, 'searchResults__cellWrapper--') and contains(@href, 'fortune500')][.//span/div]")))]
    windows_before  = driver.current_window_handle
    for my_href in my_hrefs:
        driver.execute_script("window.open('" + my_href +"');")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
        windows_after = driver.window_handles
        new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0]
        driver.switch_to_window(new_window)
        print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table/tbody/tr//td[starts-with(@class, 'dataTable__value')]/div"))).text)
        driver.close() # close the window
        driver.switch_to.window(windows_before) # switch_to the parent_window_handle
    driver.quit()
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    C. Douglas McMillon
    Darren W. Woods
    Timothy D. Cook
    Warren E. Buffett
    Jeffrey P. Bezos
    David S. Wichmann
    Brian S. Tyler
    Larry J. Merlo
    Randall L. Stephenson
    Steven H. Collis
    Michael K. Wirth
    James P. Hackett
    Mary T. Barra
    W. Craig Jelinek
    Larry Page
    Michael C. Kaufmann
    Stefano Pessina
    James Dimon
    Hans E. Vestberg
    W. Rodney McMullen
    H. Lawrence Culp Jr.
    Hugh R. Frater
    Greg C. Garland
    Joseph W. Gorder
    Brian T. Moynihan
    Satya Nadella
    Craig A. Menear
    Dennis A. Muilenburg
    C. Allen Parker
    Michael L. Corbat
    Gary R. Heminger
    Brian L. Roberts
    Gail K. Boudreaux
    Michael S. Dell
    Marc Doyle
    Michael L. Tipsord
    Alex Gorsky
    Virginia M. Rometty
    Brian C. Cornell
    Donald H. Layton
    David P. Abney
    Marvin R. Ellison
    Robert H. Swan
    Michel A. Khalaf
    David S. Taylor
    Gregory J. Hayes
    Frederick W. Smith
    Ramon L. Laguarta
    Juan R. Luciano
    .
    .
    .
    ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get companies details without using Selenium much faster and lighter.
See how I get `company_name` and `change_the_world` to extract other details.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import html

with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get("https://content.fortune.com/wp-json/irving/v1/data/franchise-search-results?list_id=2611932")
    items = response.json()[1]["items"]
    for item in items:
        company_name = html.unescape(list(filter(lambda x: x['key'] == 'name', item["fields"]))[0]["value"])
        change_the_world = list(filter(lambda x: x['key'] == 'change-the-world-y-n', item["fields"]))[0]["value"]

        response = session.get(item["permalink"])
        preload_data = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser").select_one("#preload").text
        ceo = re.search('"ceo","value":"(.*?)"', preload_data).groups()[0]

        print(f"Company: {company_name}, CEO: {ceo}, Change The World: {change_the_world}")
```

Result:

> Company: Carvana, CEO: Ernest C. Garcia, Change The World: no
>   Company: ManTech International, CEO: Kevin M. Phillips, Change The
>   World: no
>  Company: NuStar Energy, CEO: Bradley C. Barron, Change
>   The World: no
>  Company: Shutterfly, CEO: Ryan O’Hara, Change The
>   World: no
>  Company: Spire, CEO: Suzanne Sitherwood, Change The
>   World: no
>  Company: Align Technology, CEO: Joseph M. Hogan, Change
>   The World: no
>  Company: Herc Holdings, CEO: Lawrence H. Silber,
>   Change The World: no
>  ...